# Block access to Azure storage by IP

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I realize that when you create a Shared Access Signature (SAS), you can limit the SAS to only be viable from certain IP ranges.

But what I need is, to secure the Azure storage account, such that even if you have the access keys, you would be unable to access anything on the account, unless the request was coming from a set of white-listed IP ranges. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Not at this time, but it has been asked for quite a bit. The IP ACLing in a SAS is the closest you get at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**As far as I know, Azure doesn’t support the IP limitation on access keys.**

You should know that the Azure storage account & access keys are about Management Plane Security. It grants complete access which is not a good choice to share your storage account and access keys to someone else.

Depending on your needs, using SAS with IP limits is your best choice. They are useful for providing limited permissions to your storage account to clients that should not have the account key. As such, they are a vital part of the security model for any application using Azure Storage.

[Azure Storage security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-security-guide#data-plane-security)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when this started but there's an option now

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security

You can essentially block all communication with a storage account to a set of IPs, CIDR blocks or Azure VNets

Go to your storage account > Firewalls and virtual networks > select 'Selected Networks'
Then specify IPs, CIDR blocks or Azure VNets.

> **NOTE:** The moment you turn this on, it essentially blocks any connections regardless of SAS tokens they present, including access via **Azure Portal** (you'll get an access denied on the blades showing your containers.) and **Storage Explorer**. If you have apps running that use this account, make sure your restrictions include them before pressing Save.
>
> If you configured static site hosting, they will also be affected. This affects the whole account, not only blobs. So if you have apps accessing tables or files in the account, make sure you add them to the list.
>
> If you want to upload, edit, download things from your storage account and you're not in the networks specified, you will have to add your current IP.